# Can I download raspbian update packages onto a Redhat Linux server?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to create a Redhat Linux server-based Raspberry Pi repository, and I just need to know if it's possible to download the relevant update files from the Raspbian site.

Comment: http://blog.thelifeofkenneth.com/2018/01/off-grid-raspbian-repositories.html looks like something that will work on any system that has rsync and debmirror.

Answer (score 0):

Raspbian is based on Debian, not RedHat.

Getting RedHat updates requires a support agreement: distributing those to other people would be a violation of that support agreement, so the Raspberry Pi Foundation is not going to do that.

(If you want your repository to be usable to others, I recommend using CentOS as a basis instead; that way, you should not be at risk of getting on the wrong side of RedHat's lawyers. Remember that RedHat is being acquired by IBM, and *they* have very, very good lawyers.)

So, the Raspbian site is only going to have updates for Raspbian. Those updates are based on corresponding Debian updates. The versions of individual libraries and other components follow what Debian is doing (unless Raspbian has a specific reason to spend the effort to do otherwise). There is no guarantee whatsoever that those versions would in any way match the requirements of RedHat packages.

Besides, RedHat uses the `.rpm` package format, while Debian uses `.deb`. So even the low-level package management tools and libraries are going to be different.

So for several reasons, the answer is no.

Comment: So to clarify I'm not trying to download Redhat updates, I'm trying to download Raspbian updates to the Redhat server. So hopefully Redhat shouldn't be too bothered by that, do you not think I couldn't just download the relevant files from Raspbian and push them out via SSH?

Comment: Ah, *for distribution to other Raspbian systems* you mean? That's fine. You might want to read https://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror since Raspbian is based on Debian, and so the same scripts and techniques should work for efficient downloading: you'll be essentially creating a Raspbian mini-mirror for your own use.

Comment: would you happen to have a post to refer me to? I am extremely new to all of this.